# Url rewriting on Godaddy

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-6

I am working on a web application***(framework 3.5)***.I had done routing in this by using the following code:

```
http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx
```

On local machine everything running fine.But when i deploy the code on **IIS 6.0** i am getting

```
 404 (Page Not Found) Error
```

I searched a lot on web and also get many solutions for this one of them is to add

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

in web config but problem is still there.Now i find out that we have to set IIS wild card mapping on server.

**Problem:**

How we can perform Url Rewritting on shared server.

Answer (score 0):

Here it says URL Rewriting works on Windows servers that has IIS 7. Maybe that is your problem. You should see here:

[Microsoft URL Rewrite Module](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5443/microsoft-url-rewrite-module?pc_split_value=1)